# How does pine script calculate an RSI using 2 series instead of 1 and a period?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, pine-script

I have a pine script that I am trying to convert to python.

However, pine script allows RSI to have 2 series as input instead of the traditional series and period.

My question is how this is implemented, I tried the implementation on their documentation but it doesn't count for the second series :

```
pine_rsi(x, y) => 
u = max(x - x[1], 0) // upward change
d = max(x[1] - x, 0) // downward change
rs = rma(u, y) / rma(d, y)
res = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
res
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I am not and expert in Python or anything, but I think you're trying to divide by zero.

The equation for RSI is:

```
RSI= 100 - { 100 \ (1+RS) }
```

where

```
RS = SMMA(U,n) / SMMA(D,n)
```

The logic in your equation doesn't appear to account for the fact that the RS will have a zero in the denominator if the downward rma is equal to zero.  This condition occurs whenever the price trends downward for 14 consecutive periods, or whatever the period of the RSI is.

The pine editor script accounts for this by setting the RSI equal to 100 whenever the situation above occurs.

On line 6 below: the RSI is switched to 100 whenever the down rma term is equal to 0.  The second part of the line only executes when the code won't divide by zero.

```
1  //@version=3
2  study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI")
3  src = close, len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
4  up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
5  down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
6  rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
7  plot(rsi, color=purple)
8  band1 = hline(70)
9  band0 = hline(30)
10 fill(band1, band0, color=purple, transp=90)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what the Change() function will do? https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_change

Is this return simply a difference of current value and previous value?

For example Current Value is 15 and Previous Val is 10 = Answer will be 5

Comment: I don't understand the x-x[y] in trading view guide line.

Comment: @SahilPatel Yes that is what it does. [1] Means last value. [5] means 5 values back in past.

Answer (score 2):

From pine script docs:

> ```
> rsi(x,y)
> ```
>
> "If x is a series and y is integer then x is a source series and y is a length.
>
> "If x is a series and y is a series then x and y are considered to be 2 calculated MAs for upward and downward changes"

So, if you have both upward and downward changes series, `rsi` will work like this:

```
u = ["your upward changes series"]
d = ["your downward changes series"]

rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + u / d) //No need for a period value
```

Answer (score 0):

There actually is such a thing as a "second series" in Pine Script. From the documentation:

```
rsi(x,y)

"If x is a series and y is integer then x is a source series and y is a length.
If x is a series and y is a series then x and y are considered to be 2 calculated MAs for upward and downward changes"
```

However it doesn't explain what the purpose is, as there is no length input to the rsi() function - what is Pine supposed to be doing with the data?

Like the OP, I'd also like to know the purpose of 2 series as input, to port to python. This hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

for x and y series

```
pine_rsi( x, y ) => 
  res = 100 - 100 / (1 + x / y)
  res
```

Answer (score -1):

> *how this is implemented .. **it doesn't count for the second series** :* ?

### There is no such thing as a " *second* " serie

---

Let's review the code,
the original looks this way  :

```
pine_rsi( x, y ) => 
     u   = max(x - x[1], 0) // upward change
     d   = max(x[1] - x, 0) // downward change
     rs  = rma(u, y) / rma(d, y)
     res = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
     res
```

yet, if we decode the logic into a bit better readable shape, we get :

```
pine_rsi(        aTimeSERIE, anRsiPERIOD ) => 
     up   = max( aTimeSERIE
               - aTimeSERIE[1], 0 )     //         upward changes

     down = max( aTimeSERIE[1]
               - aTimeSERIE,    0 )     //       downward changes

     rs   = ( rma( up,   anRsiPERIOD )  //  RMA-"average" gains  over period
            / rma( down, anRsiPERIOD )  //  RMA-"average" losses over period
              )

     res  = 100 - 100 / ( 1 + rs )      //  

     res
```

which is exactly what has J. Welles Wilder named the Relative Strength Index, isn't it?

So just pass the proper data-types, as the calling signature prescribes, and you are done.